# High Moon (The Lotus Caves) Floating Eyeballs

Tags: plot-explanation, high-moon

[**High Moon**](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2327948/) is a (very loose) TV adaptation of the 1969 book *The Lotus Caves*. It was started as a pilot for a Syfy TV series, but eventually the series was declined. The Pilot was rigged into an original TV Movie instead.

Of course, the movie ends in a cliff hanger. Yama starts to asphyxiate when her suit runs out of oxygen while underground on the Moon. She drops the force field in her helmet and is surprised to be able breath. The red lotus that the movie revolves around is producing oxygen. She sees a light and finds an entire cavern full of bioluminescent flowers and plants and trees and water (Very Journey to the Center of the Earth). **The camera pans away and boom, a ton of floating eyeballs in the middle of the sky are shown.** Cue Credits.

[image: The frame is dark except for a patch in the lower middle that has a tracery of tangled blue illuminated lines and red lights. Spotted around the frame, the largest in the middle, are seven eyes, showing the iris, pupil and part sclera as viewed between the lids.]

These same eyes were seen earlier in the Indian moon Colony base. Very cryptically, and without explanation. Since the Movie ends, and the series was not ordered, no canon is forthcoming. I've attempted to look for answer on what the eyes were, or why they were there but couldn't find anything. **Does anyone have any links or information on the eyeballs, or how the series would have progressed in general? Any interviews?**

Note that the movie does not follow the books. At least the setting is similar, but major changes between history and cast and everything.

Comment: I didn't want to make this an answer, because it doesn't really answer your question, but Bryan Fuller does say in the following interview that there was a plan and that the eyes, along with other things *would of paid off/have gotten explained: https://ew.com/article/2014/09/15/high-moon-bryan-fuller-syfy/